# How would a site, like w3schools, run many languages locally?

Tags: javascript, html, translate

I'm working on a portfolio website, and I thought it would be cool to be able to run my scripts in python, java, js, rust, etc locally in the browser
[Here's an example of this from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_lambda)

I'm guessing they have a translation layer to javascript, but in the event that they're actually running C++ here, does anyone know how this might be done or generalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not translate those languages to JavaScript and then run it on the client - that would be a herculean task to get right, especially for multiple languages. Rather, they (and the many similar sites like [try it online](https://tio.run/)) take the source code text from the client's browser, and run it *on the server*, and respond to the client with the result from the server.

To achieve something like this, you'd need

- A backend (in any language)
- Compilers/interpreters/etc for all languages you want to support
- A way for the backend to programatically call them with the user's input (which is often pretty easy)

For proof that w3schools takes the result from a server, rather than running it locally, examine the network tab of your browser, and you'll see it:

[image]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. For terminal stuff it's super intuitive but when you get to more complicated things with GUI i'm still not quite sure how that is achieved